# Mac OS OpenGL - problems with CPU usage

Tags: c++, macos, opengl, sdl, cpu

Since the Mavericks update(I'm on the 10.10 now) the debug window is showing this message :

> The function ‘CGContextErase’ is obsolete and will be removed
>   in an upcoming update. Unfortunately, this application, or a library
>   it uses, is using this obsolete function, and is thereby contributing
>   to an overall degradation of system performance.

I'm creating an OpenGL (SDL) application, which written in C++ and now I have issues with CPU's memory because of my application(it uses 100% powers of my MacBook's Intel i5 processor). 
So, maybe it is because all of this CGContextErase function. 
How do I solve it? 
Well, maybe there are mistakes in my code :

```
//I'm using the SDL2
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

class sWindow {
public:
    SDL_Window *win;
    SDL_Surface *winSur;
    SDL_Event e;

    void createWindow(char*,int,int,int,int,Uint32);
    void update();
    void render();
    void close();

    SDL_Rect WIN_RECT;
    char WIN_TITLE = NULL;
    int WIN_ID = -1;
};

SDL_Rect newRect(int x, int y, int w, int h) {
    SDL_Rect returnRect;

    returnRect.x = x;
    returnRect.y = y;
    returnRect.w = w;
    returnRect.h = h;

    return returnRect;
}

//The window, where the content(surface) will be rendered.
sWindow win1;

//Window's construct
void sWindow::createWindow(char* title, int x, int y, int w, int h, Uint32 flags) {
    win = SDL_CreateWindow(title, x, y, w, h, flags);
    winSur = SDL_GetWindowSurface(win);

    WIN_RECT = newRect(x, y, w, h);
    WIN_ID = SDL_GetWindowID(win);
}

//The logic and render actions...
void sWindow::update() {

}

//Window's destructor
void sWindow::close() {
    SDL_DestroyWindow(win);
    SDL_FreeSurface(winSur);
}

//Main loop control
bool quit = false;

//Initilize the OpenGL and other libs(SDL2)
bool inited() {
    bool result = true;

    if (SDL_INIT_VIDEO <= 0) {
        result = false;
        printf("SDL_INIT_VIDEO Failed");
    }

    return result;
}

//Main loop...
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if (inited()) {
        win1.createWindow((char*)"SpaceCode", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 380, 280, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
        while (!quit) {

            while (SDL_PollEvent(&win1.e) != 0) {
                if (win1.e.type == SDL_QUIT) {
                    quit = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    win1.close();
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This code would always result in high CPU use as there is no framerate cap in place therefore it will just try to process it as fast as possible.

See various posts below:

- http://lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/lesson14/
- https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/79490/should-i-cap-the-frame-rate-in-sdl

Plus many more searching on Google.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. It was caused by an outdated Wacom Tablet driver. If you have such a driver installed I'd recommend removing it, then reinstalling a more recent driver. That did the trick for me.

Comment: Please don't post identical answers to multiple questions. Post one good answer, then vote/flag to close the other questions as duplicates. If the question is not a duplicate, *tailor your answers to the question.*

Comment: Good feedback. Thanks. Will do.